# How do I include an S3 bucket name and region/endpoint in a single URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I have a bucket named `mybucket` in `region=us-east-1`, then I can access it using

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --region=us-east-1
```

However, that requires passing **two** pieces of information:

1. The URL `s3://mybucket`
2. The region `us-east-1` (or the endpoint, whichever)

Ideally, a URL is a *uniform* resource locator. It is great that it has the protocol (`s3`) and the bucket name, but is there an AWS S3-standard single URL that encodes both the region and the bucket name, such that I can do:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket_url_including_region_or_endpoint
```

EDIT:

To clarify, I am *not* looking for the list of endpoints. I am looking for how an s3 URL really can be a uniform resource locator, by encapsulating all of the necessary information inside it to obtain the resource (minus auth credentials, of course).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no provision in the `s3://` scheme for encoding the region.

Note also that the "U" in URL stands for *uniform*, not *universal*.

Comment: Doh! Yeah, good point. Been doing this for 25 years and still do dumb mistakes. Even so, the point of a URL is to provide a single _uniform_ resource locator, and if the region is needed but not provider, well, it ain't.

Comment: @deitch one thing to remember, I suspect, is that S3 was not originally regional.  It was geographically distributed but without a notion of regions -- everything was everywhere.  With the addition of regions, they wisely preserved the global bucket namespace, so it is *technically* still a valid resource locator, much the same as the global endpoint `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` is automatically DNS-mapped to the correct region for each bucket.  The need to know the region when making a request is (arguably) primarily an artifact of Signature Version 4's date/region/service logic.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to include the S3 region for a bucket is to include it in the URL properly.

**Note:** "s3.amazonaws.com" is often mis-used when referencing buckets in regions outside of us-east-1. It can be, and often is used to do so. But, doing so makes knowing which region you are actually operating in less obvious, and this can be problematic in some scenerios.

If you wanted to specifically reference a bucket called "mybucket" in us-east-2 then the best way to do this is one of the following:

```
Host-Style Naming: http://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Path-Style Naming: http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket
```

In either one of those examples, you will always connect to us-west-2 when referencing "mybucket".

Comment: Your assertions are correct, except OP is apparently looking for a way to do this not with proper URLs, but with code that accepts arguments in the `s3://${bucket}/${key}` *pseudo*-URL format, like aws-cli does... which (afaik) isn't possible.

Comment: I think (unfortunately) @Michael is right; you cannot do it using `s3://` since, even though it is wrapped in `http`, it is its own protocol. Try feeding that `http://` URL to any AWS SDK or CLI and it will choke on it.

Comment: @JoshuaBriefman thanks, but the edit was declined.  Edits generally should not involve such a substantial change.  Feel free to post your own answer with this content, either editing this one or deleting it and posting another.

Comment: Also, don't solicit downvotes. :) They're easy enough to get. :( Your answer, here, is **not** [*"an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) and thus **not** (imho) deserving of downvotes, even though it doesn't exactly (again, imho) address the question at hand.  Hence the reason I commented on your answer rather than casually tossing a -1 in your direction.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I appreciate the advise. I've deleted my 'comment', and I will post a second answer with that additional information. As it doesn't appear this one is without helpful information.

Comment: Correction: Host-Style Naming: http://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
(notice dot between s3 and region instead of dash). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html

Answer (score 2):

As @michael-sqlbot commented, URL and URI are not the same thing.

The S3 URL you referenced is actually an S3Uri as mentioned here.

### [AWS CLI - S3 Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)

**S3Uri: represents the location of a S3 object, prefix, or bucket.** This must be written in the form s3://mybucket/mykey where mybucket is the specified S3 bucket, mykey is the specified S3 key.

### [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

In information technology, a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters used to identify a resource. Such identification enables interaction with representations of the resource over a network, typically the World Wide Web, using specific protocols. **Schemes specifying a concrete syntax and associated protocols define each URI.**

### [Uniform Resource Locator (URL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)

A Uniform Resource Locator (URL), commonly informally termed a web address (a term which is not defined identically) is a reference to a web resource that specifies its location on a computer network and a mechanism for retrieving it. **A URL is a specific type of Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)**, although many people use the two terms interchangeably.

### So what does this all mean? URL!=URI?

According to the the definition of what a URI is, it is defined by the scheme designed for it. And, the scheme defined for it in this case, does not include a reference for region.

So the format for the URI would be correct, even if viewed by others as incomplete.

A URL is intended to help you locate an object somewhere, where as a URI is intended to reference an object and not necessarily locate it.

Comment: By the same logic `http://192.168.1.1` would not not a valid URL because of a lack of information on how to connect to it from other networks.  S3 URIs are perfectly valid URLs in any context where the region can be inferred.