# Specify AWS profile name to use when uploading Pandas dataframe to S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to upload a Panda's data-frame directly to S3 by specifying s3 url. I have a [multi-profile AWS environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html), and I would like to specify the name of the profile to use for this upload.

Since [it is not possible to specify region in the s3 url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115306/how-do-i-include-an-s3-bucket-name-and-region-endpoint-in-a-single-url), I would like to know if there is any other way I could specify the (non-default) region in the code.

I could not file any such option in the [s3fs](http://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which is used internally by `boto3` for uploading to s3.

Note that I do not want to use environment variables, or modify the default configuration in the AWS credentials files.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame()

# I would like to specify non-default profile to use here
s3_url = 's3://my_bucket/path/to/file.parquet'
df.to_parquet(s3_url)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, why not use Boto3's S3 resource/client to upload a file to a bucket by it's name? S3 is a global service and there is no region-based separation, meaning if you `list_buckets()` you get buckets in all regions, your key/profile should simply belong to the right account, and have access to the bucket. in other words, the bucket url is abstracted by boto3.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [session](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#shared-credentials-file)

```
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
    s3_client = session.client('s3')
```

[Save](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas-dataframe-to-parquet) the DataFrame to a parquet file

```
    df.to_parquet( parquet_pandas_file )
```

[Upload](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) the file to S3

```
    with open( parquet_pandas_file, 'rb' ) as s3_source_data:
        s3.upload_fileobj(s3_source_data, 'bucket_name', 'bucket_key_name' )
```

Comment: You have an error in your code. The second line of Upload should read s3.upload_fileobj(s3_source_data, 'bucket_name', 'bucket_key_name')

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to set the profile name when using s3fs command

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(profile_name='<profile name>')
with fs.open('s3://bucketname/root1/file.csv', 'w') as f:
    df.to_csv(f)
```